# How to include Angular Material in Angular 17?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Angular Material's documentation says:

```
import { MatSlideToggleModule } from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';

@NgModule ({
  imports: [
    MatSlideToggleModule,
  ]
})
class AppModule {}
```

But Angular 17 doesn't create app.module file by default. Is there any way to do that without app.module?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

import dependencies into the component instead of app.modules, add attribute standalone:true , like the code below:

```
import { MatSlideToggleModule } from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';
@Component({
  standalone:true,
  imports: [
     MatSlideToggleModule,
   ],
   selector: 'your-component',
   templateUrl: './your.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./your.component.scss']
 })
```

Answer (score 9):

Angular v17 onwards, standalone is default via CLI

Which means when you create new project it wont have any modules in it

As a workaround it is possible to create a module-based app by using the `--no-standalone` flag : `ng new --no-standalone` which will create a app.modules.ts in your project

use this command :

```
ng new myNewApp --no-standalone
```

Follow it up with :

```
ng add @angular/material
```

Then import relevent modules from angular material to your project app.module.ts :

```
import { MatSlideToggleModule } from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';

@NgModule ({
  imports: [
    MatSlideToggleModule,
  ]
})
class AppModule {}
```