# equivalent of "app.module.ts" in Angular 17?

Tags: angular, frontend, angular17

Didn't found app.module.ts in Angular 17
What would be the equivalent of app.module.ts in Angular 17? I couldn't find app.module.ts in Angular 17. Has the structure changed, or is there a different approach for module configuration in Angular 17?
didn't found app.module.ts in Angular 17

Comment: you can create one

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/standalone-migration

Comment: this question is duplicate check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77538726/how-to-include-angular-material-in-angular-17/77539161#77539161

Answer (score 3):

From Angular v17 onwards, Standalone is now the new default for the CLI.

So when you create a new project, you won't have any modules in it if you don't specify anything.

If you want to create a project with app.module.ts you can create it by using the --no-standalone flag : ng new --no-standalone
For more: https://angular.io/tutorial/tour-of-heroes/toh-pt0

Standalone components are a feature introduced in v14. With the change in v17, the Angular team strongly recommends to use them as they are easier to use, understand and are require less boilerplate.

For tutorials using standalone components, I advise you to get a look at the new documentation site (https://angular.dev/).

Answer (score 2):

`ng new` schematics generate a standalone workspace since v17. In a standalone workspace, there is no app module. Instead your root component must be bootstrapped in the `main.ts` file. See the [standalone guide](https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components#bootstrapping-an-application-using-a-standalone-component).

If you want to generate a new workspace with a root module, run the following command:

`ng new --no-standalone`

Answer (score 0):

Angular 17+ standalone components are really easy to use and have increased my development speeds when using nx. You essentially have your imports, providers, et. in component declaration and lazy load your components into your application.