# How to use Angular Material in Angular 17?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular17

I noticed that in version 17 of Angular, the app.module.ts file is not created, where imports from Angular Material fit. I know that there is a separate command in Angular 17 to create a project with the app.module.ts file and in this case everything works. I don’t understand how to use Angular Material in version 17 of Angular, where to enter imports?
I found a solution to this problem, namely adding the line standalone:true to main.ts and adding imports to the same file, but this method does not work for me.
That is, my main question: How to use Angular Material without the app.module.ts file and where to enter imports?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: this question is duplicate check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77538726/how-to-include-angular-material-in-angular-17/77539161#77539161

Answer (score 1):

Projects generated with Angular 17 don't have an `app.module.ts` anymore. Instead the `app.component.ts` is standalone. If you want to import an Angular Material module (or any other module) in a component, just add it to the **component's** `imports`:

```js
@Component({
  standalone: true,
  imports: [MatButtonModule],
  template: `<button mat-button>My Button</button>`,
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

For a deeper dive, check [Angular's official standalone component guide](https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components).